# Removing a table row and appending the same table row at the end of the table

Tags: jquery

I want to achieve the following, I need to remove a table row from a table with id `#emailTable` and then appending the exact same row to the end of the table and then hiding the appended table row using **JQuery**.

To remove the table I do the following

```
$("#rowid_"+id).remove();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var a;
a = $("#rowid_"+id).html(); // store the content on a
$("#rowid_"+id).remove(); // remove the node
$('table').append(a);// append the content on table
$("#rowid_"+id).hide();//hide the appended node
```

I hope it works :)

Comment: It works, I took your answer and altered it a bit var row = $("#rowid_"+id).clone().appendTo("#emailTable").hide();
            $("#rowid_"+id).remove(); and then it still worked. Thx, will accept your answer

Comment: Roland, cloning the node is very smart solution, learned new thing today :)

Answer (score 9):

Assuming, `#rowid-id` refers to `<tr>` element, simply do

```
$("#rowid_"+id).appendTo('table');
```

That will move your row element after the last element of your `table`.

Take a look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KJeqp/)

Comment: I like @Boris Guéry solution.. quick easy and to the point.

Are there any downsides to this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Boris Guéry answer is correct if there is only 1 (one!) table in your page.

Here is a version which works for a page with more than one table.

```
$("#tr_Row_" + id).appendTo($("#tr_Row_" + id).closest("table"));
```

Explanation: second part

```
$("#tr_Row_" + id).closest("table") // get the parent-table of the row.
```

Explanation: first part

```
$("#tr_Row_" + id).appendTo(...parentTable...) // remove row from the current table
                                               // and append it as last child to the 
                                               // parentTable
```